# How do I change the main kaobook font to the default LaTeX font?

Tags: fonts, kaobook

[Kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook)'s `kao.sty` file contains the section `encoding and fonts`:

```
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
    \xetexorluatextrue
\else
    \ifluatex
        \xetexorluatextrue
    \else
        \xetexorluatexfalse
    \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
    \RequirePackage{amssymb} % Must be loaded before unicode-math
    \RequirePackage[force]{filehook} % Fixes an error
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math} % Math fonts in xetexorluatex
    \setromanfont[
        Scale=1.04
    ]{Libertinus Serif}
    \setsansfont[
        Scale=1
    ]{Libertinus Sans}
    \setmonofont[
        Scale=.89
    ]{Liberation Mono}
    \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
    \ifluatex
    \else
        %\RequirePackage{morewrites} % Fix some errors related to floats
    \fi
\else
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8 encoding in the input (.tex) file
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % utf8 encoding in the output (.pdf) file

    \RequirePackage{amssymb} % Math symbols, including \blacktriangleright, used for bullets
    \RequirePackage[scaled=.97,helvratio=.93,p,theoremfont]{newpxtext} % Serif palatino font
    \RequirePackage[vvarbb,smallerops,bigdelims]{newpxmath} % Math palatino font
    \RequirePackage[scaled=.85]{beramono} % Monospace font
    \RequirePackage[scr=rsfso,cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % Mathcal from STIX, unslanted a bit
    %\RequirePackage{morewrites} % Fix some errors related to floats
\fi

% When using the Palatino (newpxtext) font, it is better to use a 
% slightly larger stretch.
%\setstretch{1.10}
\linespread{1.07} % Give Palatino more leading (space between lines)
```

Deleting the block after the third `\else` (outlined on the left) does change the font, but it also messes up any linking settings and prints the glossary on a page in front of the title page and not lined up nicely, but in one block of text. By messing up linking, I mean that there are now blocks around the TOC entries, for instance.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a better answer to this, you might delete (or comment)
`\RequirePackage[scaled=.97,helvratio=.93,p,theoremfont]{newpxtext}`
or change it to
`\RequirePackage[]{lmodern}`